# Android: data-binidng: disable click

Tags: android-databinding

I want to disable click when variable `isAgree`  is false:

here code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <data>

        <import type="android.view.View" />

        <variable
            name="handler"
            type="myproject.ui.SubscribeBrandDialogFragment" />

    </data>

     <TextView
                android:id="@+id/subscribeTextView"
                android:layout_width="185dp"
                android:layout_height="40dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/default_margin"
                android:background="@{handler.isAgree ? @drawable/border_enable_bg : @drawable/border_disable_bg}"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:onClick="@{handler.isAgree ? handler.onClickSubscribe() : null}"
                android:textColor="@{handler.isAgree ? @color/color_primary : @color/disable_text_color}"            />

</layout>
```

But I get error in `android:onClick` :

```
e: [kapt] An exception occurred: android.databinding.tool.util.LoggedErrorException: Found data binding errors.
****/ data binding error ****msg:Cannot find the setter for attribute 'android:onClick' with parameter type void on android.widget.TextView.
file:myproject\layout\subscribe_brand_dialog.xml
loc:100:31 - 100:81
****\ data binding error ****

    at android.databinding.tool.processing.Scope.assertNoError(Scope.java:112)
    at android.databinding.annotationprocessor.ProcessDataBinding.doProcess(ProcessDataBinding.java:101)
    at android.databinding.annotationprocessor.ProcessDataBinding.process(ProcessDataBinding.java:65)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.kapt3.ProcessorWrapper.process(annotationProcessing.kt:131)
```

I know that I can fix this by java code. But I want fix this ONLY in xml layout.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use lambda expression.

```
android:onClick="@{() -> handler.isAgree ? handler.onClickSubscribe() : null}"
```

Answer (score 0):

Well a couple things. 
First, I would use the controls properties the way they are meant to be used. Setting null on the click handler does not appropriately handle the UI element, you are merely hacking.

You should be disabling the click property or focus property based on your boolean, rather then toggling click handlers to null.

Secondly typically when you are doing Terinaray statements in xml click events I have seen the handler::methodName used rather then handler.methodName to ensure it is handled property in the generated databinding classes for onClick.

Lastly, if you already have the agreed boolean, why not just handle the click in the code. You literally saved yourself 1 line for another line if you think about it.

myClick()
   if(isAgree) . //you saved this
.
now you have to do this
ObservableBoolean<> myBool = new ObservableField()
myBool.set(true/false)

of you are adding the
@Bindable to a method.
Either way you are not really saving code by doing the boolean check in the xml and you lose your ability to unit test it or debug. Just my two cents.